# The system cannot find the file C:\Users\nohar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd

**When did this happen?**

Randomly, after I installed an `npm` package (`npm install jquery-resizable-dom`) <sup>(probably not related)</sup>, now I get this error when running `python`, (note that `py` and `pip` still function properly):

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\nohar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe.
```

I have researched this issue, and the answers I found haven't worked. I have added `C:\Users\nohar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` to PATH, and PYTHONPATH, still nothing.

`python.exe` **DOES** in fact exist in `C:\Users\nohar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\`

[image]

**Other Information**

- I am not using a python environment, and I am not using an IDE like Pycharm, or any text editor.
- I am using account `C:\Users\Areg`

I realize that I can just make an alias for `py`, but I do want a better and more reliable solution, if such solution exists.

#### Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I cant figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: `python.exe` and `python3.exe` in directory `C:\Users\nohar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` have both a file size of 0 KB. It looks like these two files are just symbolic links to `python.exe` in a directory which does not exist anymore. Find out where the most recent installed version of `python.exe` is really installed and recreate the symbolic links using [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to fix the Python configuration issue.

Comment: This seemed to work! Thank you so much!

Comment: The whole point of the `py.exe` launcher is so you're not futzing around with your `PATH`. Why not use it? It's really the superior option on Windows.

Comment: I have a lot of build files that use `python`, and I don't to go through the hassle of changing all of those build files